# Bug in "Publish later" regarding possibility to choose time

Tags: publishing, experience-space

There is a bug in the feature to "Publish later" in Tridion Sites. When choosing a future date, it's not possible to choose a time on that day that is previous to the present time. So in this example, the date when I do this is September 7, and the time is 13:47. So when I want to publish my page on September 12, I choose that date. But then all the hours/minutes that are before 13:47 are greyed out and not possible to choose. This would be logical for September 7, but not for September 12.

[image: Screenshot of Publish later]

Comment: Nasty one. Can you please also specify the version of Tridion Sites you're on?

Comment: Can you please also specify what browser and country timezone set it up on your computer?

Comment: Nuno Linhares: It says Build 9.6, Build number 12, Build timestamp 20211119.

Comment: @Velmurugan : I use Chrome (Version 115.0.5790.99), and the timezone is "(UTC +01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien".

Comment: Yeah, It seems like a bug, Workaround is to type the minutes and seconds manually. R&D looking into this issue to be fixed to release part of Tridion Sites 10.0 ES Update 1,

Answer (score 1):

The Tridion Sites 10 UX Update is now available for installation as a mandatory 10.0 hotfix. This update fixes the above issue and also includes the following improvements and fixes:

Improvements

- New Insights area extension point supporting the addition, removal,
  and reordering of panels.
- Publishing Queue for viewing and managing
  publish transactions.
- Additional request filters for the Items in
  Progress and Activities lists.
- Free-text filters for expediting client-side search.
- Date range filtering in lists.
- Newly configured columns are appended to the end of the table. This allows users to customize column order.
- The Export command now only exports the selected item(s). This change makes it possible to export search results from lists. The exported data also includes some additional columns compared to 10.0.
- User interface state (e.g., selection, expanded tree nodes, search query) is preserved when switching between views.
- Users can now insert a lang attribute to specify the language of a text selection in the rich text editor.
- Users will be notified on completion of their publish transactions even if the publish action was performed in a different tab or session.

Resolved Issues:

- Experience Space will now indicate when there are licensing errors.
- Resolved an issue where extension field values were not updated when using `renderField` as an input.
- Fixed an issue with incorrect line spacing for rich text fields in read only view.
- Resolved possible text overflow issue when displaying search results.
- Resolved an issue with some user interface strings for the rich text editor only being available in English.
- Fixed an issue where the Insights panel would incorrectly show data for the parent of the selected item.
- Resolved issue with keyboard shortcuts for item actions not working.
- Fixed an issue where pressing Enter in a rich text field would scroll the entire page.
- Resolved an issue with incorrect editing buttons being displayed for components in workflow.
- In the rich text editor, inserting a component link around around a selection (image or formatted text) no longer deletes the selection.
- Scheduling deployment no longer sets an incorrect time for users with a timezone offset to UTC.
- A linked multimedia schema defined on a folder is no longer ignored when creating multimedia components via upload.
- Filtering of numeric values in a select control now works as expected.
- Users can now open/edit components based on a schema that does not have a major version.
- Fixed issue with intrusive publish notifications.
- Resolved an issue which could prevent users specifying a valid time when scheduling deployment.
- Default publish priorities defined on target types are no longer ignored.
- Default priority can now be overridden when unpublishing.
- Fixed an issue where the item in progress list would not load after a refresh.
- Extensions now have access to items selected in the table.
- Resolved an issue where navigation to an external content item fails due to the 1000-item limit when requesting ECL items.

The Tridion Sites 10.0 UX Update also introduces the following Rest API improvements:

- For the lockedItems endpoint:
  The 'lockUserId' filter was added to return the results based on the user who locked the items.
  If specified, then the 'forAllUsers' filter is irrelevant and is ignored.
- For the activityInstances endpoint:
  The 'OwnerId' filter was added to return the results for the given activity owner.
  The 'AssigneeId' was added to return the results for the given activity assignee.
  If either 'OwnerId' or 'AssigneeId' are specified, then the 'forAllUsers' filter is irrelevant and is ignored.
  If both 'OwnerId' and 'AssigneeId' are specified, then activity instances for the given owner or assignee are returned.
- For the publishing/transactions endpoint:
  The 'priority' filter was added to only include Publish Transactions with the given priority.
  The 'state' filter was added to only include Publish Transactions with the given state.
  To improve performance, the following properties are now excluded from the response:

  - Processed items
  - Resolved items